# <ol> sublist showing numbers & upper alpha

Tags: html, css

I used the following code to get an ordered sub-list to be upper-alpha.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300&display=swap');

div.container {
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.container p {
  font-family: Garamond;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul {
  font-family: Garamond;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}

ul li {
  font-family: Garamond;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

ol ol.alpha {
  counter-reset: alpha;
}

ol ol > li {
  list-style: none;
  position: realtive;
}

ol ol.alpha > li:before {
  counter-increment: alpha;
  content: counter(alpha, upper-alpha) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Navigate to the <a href="http://facebook.com/adsmanager/audiences" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Audiences</a> dashboard inside Ads Manager.
    <br>
    <br><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thinkific/file_uploads/55241/images/811/e84/c6f/Step-by-Step__1.gif" style="width: auto; max-width: 100%; height: auto;" class="fr-fic fr-dib">
    <br>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>Click <strong>Create Audience</strong>, then <strong>Custom Audience</strong>.
    <br>
    <br><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thinkific/file_uploads/55241/images/64e/80f/32c/Step-by-step__2.png" style="width: 200px; max-width: 100%;" class="fr-fic fr-dib fr-fil">
    <br>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>On the pop-up, select <strong>Website</strong>.
    <br>
    <br><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thinkific/file_uploads/55241/images/cb0/8f3/a78/Website_Step__3.png" style="width: auto; max-width: 100%; height: auto;" class="fr-fic fr-dib fr-fil">
  </li>
  <li>On the <em>Create a Website Custom Audience&nbsp;</em>pop-up:
    <ol class="alpha">
      <li>&nbsp;Confirm <strong>All website visitors</strong> is selected.</li>
      <li>&nbsp;Change <em>in the past 30 days</em> to <strong>180 days</strong>.&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;Name the audience:<strong>&nbsp;(*Brand Code*) Website</strong>.</li>
      <li>&nbsp;Click <strong>Create Audience</strong>.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

The issue I'm running into is that the sub-list is showing numbering and upper alpha:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbcp2.png)

How do I remove the numbers before the alphabetized list?

As some background I have just been googling how to do this and have never coded before. I hope this makes sense and I've included all the necessary info.

Thank you in advance for any insight into this.

Comment: add your html also

Comment: The style tag only goes inside the head. Seems to be working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li>test</li>
    <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>another test</li>
            <li>another test2</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ul {
            font-family: Garamond;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: none;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            list-style-type: upper-alpha;
        }
        
        ul li {
            font-family: Garamond;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: none;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }
        
        ol ol.alpha {
            counter-reset: alpha;
        }
        
        ol ol > li {
            list-style: none;
            position: realtive;
        }
        
        ol ol.alpha > li:before {
            counter-increment: alpha;
            content: counter(alpha, upper-alpha) ". ";
        }
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/190qksfj/1/

Comment: I'm looking for:

    <ol>
         <li>test</li>
            <ol class="alpha">
                <li>testing</li>
                <li>testing</li>
            </ol>
    </ol>

Comment: It looks like this:

1. test
2. Test
     1. A.
     2. B.

I want it to look like this:

1. test
2. Test
     A.
     B.